# Add HTML Attribute Automatically Using Userscript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

One can manually add a html attribute to a webpage element (by browser's "inspect element" command) with the desired result, but I really needed to do it automatically so after some search, I realized UserScripts are the way to go. Unfortunately all my attempts didn't work.
As an example:
Let's say I want to add an attribute to the input box on the current page; so this:
    `<input name="q" type="text" ... class="f-input js-search-field ">`
Becomes this:
    `<input name="q" foo="something" type="text" ... class="f-input js-search-field ">`
And my non working userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          SO
// @description   add attribute
// @include       https://stackoverflow.com/
// @include       https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
var j = document.getElementByClassName("f-input js-search-field ");
var foo = j.innerHTML;
foo = foo.replace("type","foo="something" type");
j.innerHTML = foo;
```

Why isn't it working?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you picked uberscripts just to solve this? Im not sure what uberscripts are but you can achieve this easily with plain javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: @MarkBaijens Thank you so much sir, Finally found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use instead

```
j.setAttribute('type' , yourValue)
```

if you want to add a new attribute

```
j.setAttribute('yourtype',yourValue)
```

Comment: made it work thanks to MarkBaijens's comment, and at the exact same time you posted the answer. you guys are great !